# How to list all packaged installed/upgraded from '-proposed'?

Tags: package-management, updates

I was wondering if there is any way to list all packages which have been installed/upgraded from the `<release>-proposed` channel (for 16.04 this is `xenial-proposed`)?

Preferably I would like to know the following things in the output:

- The package name
- Reason for upgrade and means by which it was done (if it was a manual one or if it was installed as a dependency of another package(s), if so, which other package(s))
- The version of the package and which version it was upgraded from (if it was upgraded and not newly installed)

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, but the solution should also work on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20. A script could probably achieve the desired output.

Comment: For your main question `apt list --installed | grep xenial-proposed` will suffice I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a script which should at least list them up:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
search="proposed"
for name in $(apt-cache search '' | sort -d | awk '{print $1}')
    do
    pkg="$(apt-cache policy "$name")"
    if [ "$(grep "(none)" <<<"$pkg")" == "" ] && [ "$(grep "$search" <<<"$pkg")" != "" ]
        then
        pkn="$(echo "$pkg" | head -n 2)"
        source=$(grep "$search" <<<"$pkg" | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4;}')
        echo "$pkn"
        echo "$source"
        echo
    fi
done
```

You can check that it works if you change `proposed` to `main`.